# DynamoDB QueryRequest not returning all the results

Tags: scala, amazon-dynamodb

```
    val queryReq: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.QueryRequest = new com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.QueryRequest(tableName)
                    .withIndexName(...)
                    .addKeyConditionsEntry(..., new com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.Condition()
                                        .withAttributeValueList(Seq(new com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue(...)):_*)
                                        .withComparisonOperator(...))
                    .addKeyConditionsEntry(..., new com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.Condition()
                                        .withAttributeValueList(Seq(new com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue().withN(...)):_*)
                                        .withComparisonOperator(...))
                    .withScanIndexForward(scanDirection)
                    .withLimit(5000000)
```

This query is having withLimit = 5000000, but only returned about 3000 results. Is there a limit in how much data being returned by dynamodb in each query? If so, is there a clean way to overcome this limit?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. So I will answer my own question:
I can just create a while loop that appends to the result set when getLastEvaluatedKey() is not null nor empty.

Comment: Why did you chose QueryResult vs DynamoDBQueryExpression?